# returning only first element from for loop

Tags: python, web-services

I have a url in which i would like to get a list of products name when i print it i am getting all the products name,I am creating a web service so i have to returned the products name ,but i am only getting the first element ,i have moved the products name into a list and then    returned it ,but still i am getting an ERROR

```
AttributeError("'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'",)
```

Here is my code

```
from bottle import route, run
import urllib2
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


import sys
import csv
import re

@route('/hello')
def hello():
  texts=list();
  result='  ,'
  mech = Browser()
  url = "http://www.amazon.com"
  page = mech.open(url)

  html = page.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  last_page = soup.find('div', id="nav_subcats")
  for elm in last_page.findAll('a'):
    texts = elm.text
    texts=texts.replace(",",";")
    links = elm.get('href')
    links=url+links
    alltexts=texts+links
    texts.append(alltexts)
    return texts

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: really untidy question, just as untidy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this bit:

`...
    alltexts=texts+links
    texts.append(alltexts)
    return texts`

Apart from the append as mentioned by DhruvPathak, there are a couple of other issues:

1) You are concatenating texts & links and assigning to alltexts, but then you are trying to append this back to texts.

2) Your return is inside the loop, so will happen after the first iteration. **This is why you only get the first element returned**

I think you need something more like

```
alltexts = []
for elm in last_page.findAll('a'):
    texts = elm.text
    texts=texts.replace(",",";")
    links = elm.get('href')
    links=url+links
    alltexts.append(texts+links)
return alltexts
```

Comment: I can't comment above as I don't have enough rep; I've updated my answer to clarify the reason about only getting the first element. Move the return out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying append ( which is a list method ) on a unicode string.

```
>>> texts = []
>>> texts.append(123)
>>> texts
[123]
>>> texts = u"Test"
>>> texts.append(" Hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: ok ,i have replaced texts.append(texts) ,Now iam only getting the first element ,any suggestions please